# If $f(0) = 0$, then, is $\mathrm{lim}_{x\to0} xf'(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Is the above claim true? I think that it is. I am assuming that $f$ is continuous and differentiable at $0$. My not-so-rigorous attempt:

$$ \mathrm{lim}_{x \to 0} x f'(x) = \mathrm{lim}_{x \to 0} \mathrm{lim}_{h\to0} x \frac{f(h)}{h} $$

Now choosing the approach direction $x=h$, we see that the limit equals $0$ because $f(0)=0$. Is the idea correct? If not, can this condition be true under some additional constraints?

Comment: What about $f\left(x\right)=\log \left(x+1\right)$?

Comment: I think the left hand side is valid if $f'$ is defined near 0 since the limit is taken on the function $xf'\left(x\right)$ itself.

Comment: @Eric, sure that provides a counter-example. Where is my line of reasoning mistaken for $f(x)=\mathrm{log}(1+x)$? Is it that we cannot compute the derivative separately?

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is quite right for me, tbh, because... when you write $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f\left(h\right)}{h}$ on the right hand side, it seems like you have fixed $x$ as 0. However, $x$ is moving toward 0 (in any direction).

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} xf^{\prime}(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} x \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and not what you have written.

Comment: that "choosing the approach direction $x=h$" makes no sense that I can see.

Comment: I think $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2), x\ne0$; $f(0)=0$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable is not sufficient.

For example, set $f(x) = x^2 \sin(x^{-2})$ if $x \ne 0$, and $f(0)=0$.

Then $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h \sin(h^{-2}) = 0$.

But when $x \ne 0$, $f'(x) = 2x \sin(x^{-2}) - x^2 \times 2x^{-3} \sin(x^{-2})$, so $xf'(x) = 2x^2 \sin(x^{-2}) - 2 \sin(x^{-2})$, which has no limit as $x \to 0$.